# Web Api Server Side Processing and DataTables parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

I'm trying to create an object that represents the values that datatables supplies to my web api call, which I'll then route to another api that actually returns the values (to separate the datatables nonsense from the api interface).

After researching a bit on the datatables wiki I ended up with the following objects defined:

```
public class DataTableParameters
{
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public order[] order { get; set; }
    public column[] columns { get; set; }
}

public class order
{
    public int column { get; set; }
    public string dir { get; set; }
}

public class column
{
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool searchable { get; set; }
    public bool orderable { get; set; }
    public search search { get; set; }
}

public class search
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public bool regex { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I try to use them as arguments to the DataTables api controller, it comes out null:

```
    public DataTableResult Get(DataTableParameters parameters) //parameters is null!
    {
         return new DataTableResult();
    }
```

As far as I understood it, model binding should be reading the result and applying it to my object. This is an example call to the api from the front end:

```
Key Value
Request GET /MVC/api/DataTables?action=Get&draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=1&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=2&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=3&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1440437669357 HTTP/1.1
```

Why is my parameters object null, and how can I fix it?

Edit: I also attempted this:

```
 public DataTableResult Get(int draw, int start, int length, column[] columns, order[] order)
    {
        return new DataTableResult();
    }
```

But I get "Can't bind multiple parameters ('columns' and 'order') to the request's content."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UGH less than 10 minutes later, I need a [FromUri] attribute on the parameters.

```
 public DataTableResult Get([FromUri]DataTableParameters parameters)
 {
      return new DataTableResult();
 }
```